Limite in using google colab pro
I am subscribed in google colab pro in 15 June (this should give me 1 month to use the GPU). I trained my model over the night (2 AM - 9 AM) but at the morning I can not use the GPU (L100) or L4GPU.
Why? what is the problem?


As described in the bottom section of your screenshot, you have exhausted your compute units.
When you are subscribed to Colab Pro, you receive a certain number of "compute units" monthly. As you use the Colab VMs, they consume compute units at a certain rate. When you run out of compute units, the limitation of free Colab users will apply. This is why you can only select CPU, T4 and TPUv2 instances.
From the Colaboratory FAQ:

Paid users whose compute unit balance is exhausted will revert to the free-of-charge tier policies and restrictions until the balance is increased.

The type of hardware accelerator affects the rate of compute unit consumption. For example, an A100 instance consumes about 10 compute units per hour, while an CPU instance will consume less than 1 compute unit during the same period (as of writing.) Although unofficial, this website has a table of hardware choices and compute unit consumption.
You can check your current balance by navigating the "Runtime" menu -> "View Resources".
To use high-end accelerators again, you need to increase your balance. To do so, you have two options:

Wait until the next billing cycle, or
Purchase additional compute units (from the "Runtime" menu -> "Change Runtime" -> "Purchase additional compute units")

